# Upgrading PayPal payment to Orders API, the testing account didn't receive any money after finish the payment

Tags: rest, paypal, orders

I'm trying to implement the new PayPal Orders API, here is what I did:

1. Create a developer account, add an app name and then I have Client Id and Secret.
2. Use OrderCreateRequest to create an Order
3. Get approvel_url from the resposne->result->links
4. Redirect to this approvel_url and finish the payment
5. Paypal will redirect back to my website.

But I never got any thing from the PayPal testing account,Please, what did I miss?

Edit:
On No.4, when redirects to the PayPal page, somehow it only shows 'Continue' button on the page, not the 'make payment' button.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing:

6. Display an order review page to the payer.
7. Capture the order with an API call, which (if successful) will return the transaction ID in the purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0] object.
8. On success, display a thank you/confirmation page.

Without the final capture API call, there is no PayPal transaction.

---

You are also still using an old integration method based on redirects, which is for old websites. Current PayPal Checkout integrations use no redirects. At all.

Instead of redirecting, make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). When a capture response is successful, store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) right before sending your return JSON.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237148/discussion-between-jack-and-preston-phx).